# Delaying application while UIAlertView is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I added an Alert view, asking for user input, at the start of my app.  The app works fine without the Alert view.  But with the code for the Alert view added, part of the UI is blacked out after hitting the 'ok' button on the alert.

I'm not well versed in ios, but is there a good way to delay the app from running until the Alert (text input) is completed (ok button pressed).  This might avoid whatever is causing the screen to go black in one section.  Apparently the app is executing while the alert is active, and the alert is affecting the UI.  Basically, I am asking the user to input their phone number via an alert that will be used later in the app.

Comment: Create a custom alert with subclass of `UIView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When alert view is shown on screen, getting back ground dimmed (reduced alpha) is a normal thing and is practiced by iOS.

However, if you feel some part of the code you want to run only on tap on OK button on alert, move that method call to OK button action handler.

Comment: This worked.  Fortunately I didn't need to add a new button press, but rather simply added it to the code for to an existing button that the user presses first after the app starts.  This solved the problem and keeps the UI clean.  I'm only guessing, but apparently doing the alert automatically at start up while the initilization/setup code was being executed caused the blackout I was observing on the screen, interfering with some custom views.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Typically we show alert after app is stable. If you want to show alert while app is being initialized these issues may occur. You can add a temporary background view for the sake of this alert. If you are using UIAlertController that would be fairly easy.